# Can a bag of holding be put into a Leomond's Secret Chest?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, extradimensional-space

***Extradimensional** and **non-dimensional** terms are interchangable.*

*Leomond's secret chest* is the foundation spell by which all magic containers that function like a *bag of holding* are formed, but the chest itself does not have the non-dimensional tag, nor does it reduce the weight of its contents, nor is it described to have a weight limit.  Space seems to be the only factor, with no penalty mentioned for exceeding that capacity.

A *belt of hidden pouches*, *bag of holding*, *heward's handy haversack*, *chest of holding*, each of these are defined as to be an extra dimensional/non-dimensional space.

The secret chest is described as non-magical by the spell, whereas the bag of holding types are magical.

> The chests are nonmagical and can be fitted with locks, wards, and so on, just as any normal chat can be.

Can Leomond's secret chest be summoned while resting in a rope trick?

Comment: Welcome to the stack! This is an interesting question. That being said, its last paragraph seems like an additional question that's unrelated to the main one about whether you can put a bag of holding in a chest enhanced via *Leomund's secret chest.* Normally, we discourage multiple questions from being asked per question because they break our answer-upvoting system - unless there's some reason why it's important that you ask it as part of this question, instead of in a separate question?

Comment: @GMJoe They lay out the assumption that "Extradimensional and non-dimensional terms are interchangable." and equate them to both instances, so in this written form the question clearly equates both instances. VtLo. Just seems like an assumption that we can answer fairly clearly.

Comment: Thanks GMJoe, I'm a long term lurker, but I've come across some circumstances with my players that begs questioning, I've come to the best place to find answers.

Answer (score 7):

### The [Secret Chest](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/secretChest.htm) is not an extradimensional space.

The chest is a normal (albeit expensive) chest that gets transported to and from the Ethereal plane.

> Can a Bag of Holding be put into a Leomond’s Secret Chest?

Yes.

> Can Leomond's secret chest be summoned while resting in a rope trick?

It depends on if the Ethereal plane overlaps the [Rope Trick’s](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/ropeTrick.htm) extradimensional space and is worth a question on its own.

Comment: What about "the chest can contain up to 1 cubic foot of material per caster level (regardless of the chest’s actual size, which is about 3 feet by 2 feet by 2 feet)"? If it is not extra- or non-dimensional space, how is quoted part possible?

Comment: @annoyingimp The rules don't explain how most magic is possible, so it's not a surprise they don't explain this particular instance. Maybe it does use an extra- or non-dimensional space; maybe it uses some other way of making the chest "bigger on the inside. We can only speculate.